# Most efficient way to parse data & meta data into corresponding dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to turn data from an HTTP request into a data frame.

The via `httr` returned data is in the following format, containing meta data such as column headers and type.

Id like to convert this to a corresponding data frame: Columns based on `data$columnHeaders` - parsed from a defined set of rules (based on `data$columnHeaders$dataType` or `data$columnHeaders$name`

It seems like Problem that would have already been solved, however i can't find a proven, fast & efficient solution.

The `dput()` result of `data`:

```
data <- structure(list(columnHeaders = list(structure(list(name = "ga:date", 
    columnType = "DIMENSION", dataType = "STRING"), .Names = c("name", 
"columnType", "dataType")), structure(list(name = "ga:visitors", 
    columnType = "METRIC", dataType = "INTEGER"), .Names = c("name", 
"columnType", "dataType"))), rows = list(c("20120912", "26121"
), c("20120913", "32003"), c("20120914", "38348"), c("20120915", 
"26679"), c("20120916", "26249"), c("20120917", "29867"), c("20120918", 
"31572"), c("20120919", "27576"), c("20120920", "26730"), c("20120921", 
"28598"), c("20120922", "25319"), c("20120923", "27428"), c("20120924", 
"33255"), c("20120925", "32071"), c("20120926", "28272"))), .Names = c("columnHeaders", 
"rows"))
```

Comment: Can you replace your example data above with the equivalant from `dput(yourData)`? That will let us understand how your data is structured. Other good tips on making a great question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Without being able to reproduce your data, I'd recommend something like `newData <- do.call("rbind", yourData$rows)` followed by `names(newData) <- lapply(yourData$colnames, "[")`

Comment: +1 for @Chase and the point of getting some actual data.

Comment: Thank you for the Link @Chase. I've modified the Question as suggested.

Comment: @LukasGrebe - thanks for the updated question. I gave you one solution I think should scale pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reproducible example. My suggested answer in the comments is more or less what I came up with here:

```
out <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", data[["rows"]]))
names(out) <- make.names(sapply(data[["columnHeaders"]], "[[", 1))


str(out)
#-----
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ga.date    : Factor w/ 15 levels "20120912","20120913",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ ga.visitors: Factor w/ 15 levels "25319","26121",..: 2 12 15 4 3 10 11 7 5 9 ...
head(out,3)
#-----
   ga.date ga.visitors
1 20120912       26121
2 20120913       32003
3 20120914       38348
```

Note that I used `make.names()` to ensure that the column names are valid R names...otherwise you end up with a colon in your column name, which will be problematic downstream.

I'm also going to read between the lines here and assume that your first column is supposed to represent a date and the second a number. You'll notice that R currently thinks both of these are `factor` variables. Here's how I'd go about turning them into the appropriate data types:

```
#Date column
out$ga.date <- as.Date(out$ga.date, format = "%Y%m%d")
#Numeric column
out$ga.visitors <- as.numeric(as.character(out$ga.visitors))

str(out)
#-----
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ga.date    : Date, format: "2012-09-12" "2012-09-13" "2012-09-14" ...
 $ ga.visitors: num  26121 32003 38348 26679 26249 ...
```

Now I think you've got something useful to do some analysis on. See `?as.Date` and `?strptime` for details on formatting date and date/time objects.

Comment: This looks great! Would have never thought of using something like `"[["` with `sapply`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to (a) replicate your data, (b) convert the replicated data to a data frame.

```
#(a) Replicating data 
a<-c("20120912", "26121")
b<-c("20120913", "32003") 
c<-c("20120914", "38348")
data<-rbind(a,b,c)
colnames(data)<-c("date","visitors")

#(b) Converting to data frame
str(data) #chr [1:3, 1:2]
data<-data.frame(data)
str(data) #'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables
```

Does this answer your question or did I understand you incorrectly? Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Step a unfortunately does not represent the data in the form I have it.

Comment: @LukasGrebe - it's really incumbent on you to provide the structure of your data so that we can reproduce it. Tyler's answer is perfectly valid, just not ideal for your solution. Please heed my advice in my other comment about `dput()` and give us something we can work wwith.

Comment: Sorry. I've modified the Question as @Chase suggested.

Comment: @LukasGrebe if you use this code: 
    data<-data.frame(data)

Does this answer your question?